# Getting non compacted key/value from day window based statestore

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Topology Definition:

```
 KStream<String, JsonNode> transactions = builder.stream(inputTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde));
    
     KTable<Windowed<String>, JsonNode> aggregation =
                    transactions
                            .groupByKey()
                            .windowedBy(
                                    TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(windowDuration)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(windowGraceDuration)))
                            .aggregate(() -> new Service().buildInitialStats(),
                                    (key, transaction, previous) -> new Service().build(key, transaction, previous),
                                    Materialized.<String, JsonNode, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(statStoreName).withRetention(Duration.ofSeconds((windowDuration + windowGraceDuration + windowRetentionDuration)))
                                            .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                                            .withValueSerde(jsonSerde)
.withCacheDisabled())
                            .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()));
            aggregation.toStream()
                      .to(outputTopic, Produced.with(windowedSerde, jsonSerde));
```

State Store API: Fetch key by looking up all timewindows.

```
 Instant timeFrom = Instant.ofEpochMilli(0);
    Instant timeTo = Instant.now();
    WindowStoreIterator<ObjectNode> value = store.fetch(key,timeFrom,timeTo);
    while(value.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(value.next());
            }
```

As a part of test,performed 2 transactions and it produces key 1, My requirement is to get key1 twice(current & previous) without compaction when i lookup statestore. Result always returns final result with key and final aggregated value.

Txn1 --> Key - Key1 | Value - {Count=1,attribute='test'}

Txn2 --> Key - Key1 | Value - {Count=2,attribute='test1'}

Current Behavior after statestore lookup: Always get compacted key1 with value = {Count=2,attribute='test1'}

Instead I would like to get all key1 for that window duration.

As part of solution I  did below changes but unfortunately it did not worked.

1. Disabled caching at topology level
2. cache.max.bytes.buffering to 0
3. Removing compact policy manually from internal changelog topic

Suspecting changelog topic is compacted and thus get compacted keys upon calling statestore api.

What changes are needed to get noncompated keys through statestore API?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax - Need your expert opinion. Please take a look in my question if possible.

Comment: Btw: tagging does not work this way on SO -- I did not get any notification, just came across this question while browsing...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all intermediate result, you should not use the `suppress()` operator. `suppress()` is designed to emit a single result record per window, i.e., it does the exact opposite of what you want.